# Why jQuery touch events are not working with any browsers except chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

In touch laptop jQuery touch events are working only in Google Chrome browser and it is not working with other browsers.

For example: `touchmove` event

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tcd77eqj/5/)

**Code Snippets:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("div").on("touchmove", moveE);
  function moveE(e) {    
    console.log(e.type);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:200px; width:200px;background:red;">
  TEST
</div>
```

Can anyone share information about this?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch

Comment: @Infer-on Other browser didn't provide touch support by default right?